Questions to proof of Node law / cycle law / strength
I'm currently studying Proposition 9.4 (from "Markov chains and mixing times", written by Levin and Peres) regarding flow theory, specifically the proof provided, but I'm having trouble understanding a particular aspect of it. The proposition states:
Proposition 9.4 (Node law/cycle law/strength).
If $\theta$ is a flow from $a$ to $z$ satisfying the cycle law
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^{m} r(\overrightarrow{e_i})\theta(\overrightarrow{e_i}) = 0 
\end{equation}
for any cycle $\overrightarrow{e_1}, \ldots, \overrightarrow{e_m}$ and if $|\theta| = |I|$, then $\theta = I$.
Proof: The function $f = \theta - I$ satisfies the node law at all nodes and the cycle law. Suppose $f(\overrightarrow{e_1}) > 0$ for some oriented edge $\overrightarrow{e_1}$. By the node law, $e_1$ must lead to some oriented edge $\overrightarrow{e_2}$ with $f(\overrightarrow{e_2}) > 0$. Iterate this process to obtain a sequence of oriented edges on which $f$ is strictly positive. Since the underlying network is finite, this sequence must eventually revisit a node. The resulting cycle violates the cycle law. $\square$
However, I'm having difficulty understanding where the condition $|\theta| = |I|$ is used in the proof. It seems like the proof relies solely on the cycle law and the node law. Could someone please clarify where the condition $|\theta| = |I|$ comes into play in the proof? Any insights or explanations would be greatly appreciated!
